# How does wordpress check admin username and password

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a site admin panel and wp blog and I want to login by using same username and password as that for WP blog like **admin** **admin** I searched wp folder, how does it encrypt the password and how does it check if the user is admin or not..

I just got that WP used some sort of **hash** and **md5** for encryption but do not success to create copy of that function to use it for my new panel

Answer (score 0):

It is in the wp_usermeta table > metakey column > wp_user_level
If wp_user_level for a user id is 10 then he is an admin

For the password, search for the function wp_password_hash

Answer (score 0):

The function is wp_hash_password and it could be overridden as per your request (it is pluggable and some plugins change the encryption mechanism for security reasons).